# How do I access the path parameter of AWS API Gateway? I always get "message": "Missing Authentication Token"

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

My objective is the following:

- Have REST endpoint: /api/v1/{ID}
- My lambda should be able to access {ID} and do logic

Right now my api gateway looks like:

- /

  - /api

    - /v1

      - /-id-

        - GET

I've added a "Mapping Template":

```
{"id":"$input.params('id')"}
```

When I enter the url in browser "https...../dev/api/v1/-id-" I get:

```
{ id: "" }
```

When I enter "https....../dev/api/1234", I get:

```
{ "message": "Missing Authentication Token" }
```

I didn't set up any sort of authentication stuff for the url...

My lambda code:

```
console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var query = require('querystring').parse(event.querystring)
    console.log("the query ==> ", query);
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    console.log("the context ==> ", context)
    context.succeed(event);
};
```

What am I missing that'll enable me to return the "id" when entering the url on a browser?

I also ran some java code with get requests against the url, get 403 whenever I set "-id-" to some string/number...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read the docs!!!!

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-mappings.html

resource name: anything really

resource path: THIS NEEDS TO BE {PARAM_NAME} if you want to use the url like "/api/v1/PARAM_VALUE"